# Excel - Converting a string to be URL-friendly

Tags: excel

Im trying to convert a string e.g. All the world's a stage

into something more url friendly e.g. all-the-worlds-a-stage

So far I know I can user Lowercase and substitute the spaces for dashes however is there a more suitable method for removing punctuation/non-URL-friendly characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to remove non-alphanumeric characters in Excel](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/939-excel-remove-non-alphanumeric-characters.html)

```
Option Explicit
Function Alpha(rg As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer
If rg.Count <> 1 Then
MsgBox ("Only a single cell allowed as argument")
Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To Len(rg.Text)
Select Case Asc(Mid(rg.Text, i, 1))
Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
Alpha = Alpha & Mid(rg.Text, i, 1)
End Select
Next i
End Function
```